# Get untranslated {segment_n} from translated URL with publisher

Tags: multi-language, publisher

I'm using Publisher for translations and also use the URL translation. Now I want to show a menu item "active" based on the URL. But when I get `{segment_1}` it will return the translated template. So the make an if else statement for showing a active class, I need a lot of OR function to check all different languages. That's not how it should work!

So I wont to know, can I get the default untranslated template name? I thought of something like:

```
{publisher:segment_1}
```

But this echo's nothing at all..

Is it possible what I want? And how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you emailed me about this, and it might be a bug when that variable is inside of a snippet as it appears to work when its in a template file directly.

Comment: True, same person ;) Used it in a template and now it works fine!

Comment: Brian also send me a pre release of Publisher where the issue is fixed and this `{publisher:segment_1}` tag can also be used in snippets! Great support!